# Autoupdate value in Access2010 using new value entered through another table

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I've been creating a transactional database in Access 2010 and I've run into a bit of an issue. I'm trying to have a value autoupdate which can be done using triggers in SQL but I was told I'd have to use VBA in Access to make it work.

#### Scenario:

I have a Purchases Table, Purchase Transaction Table and Products Table.

#### Purchase Table has the fields:

- PurchaseNumber (Primary Key)
- PurchaseDate

#### Purchase transactions has the fields

- Purchase_Transaction_Number + Purchase_Number (Primary Composite Key)
- Product_Code (Foreign Key)
- PurchaseTransaction_UnitCost
- PurchaseTransaction_Quantity

#### Products table has the fields:

- Product_Code (Primary Key)
- Product_Type
- Product_Quantity
- Product_SalePrice
- Supplier_Code

What I'd like help with is having the **Product_Quantity** value auto update without the use of a query being manually clicked whenever a new transaction is made. So what it would do is grab the **Product_Code + PurchaseTransaction_Quantity** in the **Purchase Transactions** table and add the value to **the Product_Quantity** field in the **Products Table**.

#### Example:

Baseball Glove Purchased 4

Original Quantity was 6, after creating the transaction it automatically updates to 10 without the use of an update query.

I'm not sure how I would go about doing this in VBA if that is the method I have to go through. If there is a way to do this without VBA that would be of great help as well.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advanced.

[**Link**](http://wikisend.com/download/100780/TestDatabase.7z) to the database if anyone wants to give it a shot.

Comment: Have you considered using an event-driven [Data Macro](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/create-a-data-macro-HA010378170.aspx)?

Comment: I did not even consider that. Thank you so much! Would I be able to add 2 macros to 1 field?

Comment: @GordThompson [This is what I have so far](http://imgur.com/wZIFCwv) I'm not entirely sure where I'm going wrong. Although I'm leaning towards it being the IF statements.

Comment: @GordThompson I've also tried changing the IF statements to an Update expression to see if that would work and I'm having no luck there either.

Comment: @GordThompson [This was my next attempt](http://imgur.com/QOR1hMo) and it also doesn't seem to be working. Not sure where I'm going wrong. If you'd like I can zip my database and share it with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following Data Macros work for me:

**After Insert**

[image: AfterInsert.png]

**After Update**

[image: AfterUpdate.png]

**After Delete**

[image: AfterDelete.png]

Comment: Thank you very much! So on the after delete query I went with something similar to the After Update Query I just didn't add the second set field option.

Comment: Alright, so the above queries do work. I just couldn't read properly. As for the After Delete query though. The .[Old] call doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: I see where I was making my mistake! Thank you very much, you've been a huge help.